# Keep getting "Invalid Markup" with Galasoft

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I am writing here as I've encountered a problem with Galasoft. When I try do the following:

```
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
```

And then use it:

```
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DeselectAllCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
```

I get the error:

`"EventToCommand" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform`

The annoying part of it is that it works on my friends laptop when he uses it, why?